# Jquery prevent specific characters using inarray

Tags: jquery

This is the code I'm using:

```
$('input').keypress(function(e){
    illkey = ['40', '41', '123', '125', '91', '93'];
    ech = e.charCode;

    if ($.inArray(ech, illkey) > -1){
        tps = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        alert(tps+' is not allowed!');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I am trying to prevent users from entering some specific characters in text or password inputs and alert them when they do so.
The problem with the code above is that it does nothing nor is it giving me any errors. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from([JQuery manual # inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)):

> The comparison between values is strict.

Strict means that the comparison is using `===` and not `==`, 3 equal signs will not convert types, hence with `===` used to compare `40` is **not equal** to `'40'`.

The problem is that your array contain strings(type `string`), and your `e.chatCode` type is `number`, you should replace:

```
ech = e.charCode; // This line to...
ech = e.charCode.toString(); // This line.
```

Or you can replace:

```
illkey = ['40', '41', '123', '125', '91', '93'];// This line to...
illkey = [40, 41, 123, 125, 91, 93]; // This line where value types are `number`
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple but I was to exhausted to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because you are comparing a string with an integer. Your keycode is an integer and your array is filled with strings. Change either one of m:

```
illkey = [40, 41, 123, 125, 91, 93];
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hswzy9rh/1/)

or

```
if ($.inArray(ech.toString(), illkey) > -1) {
...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hswzy9rh/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keypress(function(e){
    illkey = [40, 41, 123, 125, 91,93];
    ech = e.keyCode;
    console.log($.inArray(ech, illkey));
    if ($.inArray(ech, illkey) > -1){
        tps = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        alert(tps+' is not allowed!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

you should to use array like that becuase its number not a string

### [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gmp6yqp/1/)